# Prove or disprove: every countable union of recursive sets is recursive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

How can I prove or disprove that every countable union of recursive sets is recursive?

What about recursive enumerable (r.e.)? How can I prove or disprove that every countable union of r.e. sets is r.e.?

Please help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Every one-element set is recursive.

Comment: $\boxdot sddsd sad

Answer (score 5):

Take your favourite non-recursively enumerable set of natural numbers. It is countable. It is therefore a countable union of singletons, each containing one number. Singletons are r.e. and recursive. So ....